# Difference between SSAS 2005 and SSAS 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, ssas

I'm asking this question since i'm planning to book a seminar, but the provider told me that they only offer trainings for SSAS 2008 or as individual training which are expensive.

So my question: would it be worthwile to book the SSAS 2008 seminar although we're using SSAS 2005 or are the differences too big?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went through a pretty thorough 2008R2 training a year ago. It wasn't radically different from 2005, but it was different enough that you're going to face quite a bit of frustration when you can't do things in 2005, or the things you want to do are done differently. SSAS has been changing quite a lot over the last several releases. This is the [list of changes between 2005 & 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522628%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), and it's not small. The new designers are the things that are going to cause you the most pain.

Comment: Thank you for this helpful answer.  So i've to look for other training offers that target SSAS 2005 or  i have to swallow the pill. I don't see that we'll upgrade to 2008 in the near future.

Comment: I'd add dynamic named sets (sets evaluated in the context of a query rather than once at startup), which isn't mentioned explicitly in the article but is quite useful.  First appeared in 2008.